# Kafka-streams: Why do all partitions get assigned to the same consumer in the consumergroup?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

**Background**

Several machines generate events. These events get sent to our Kafka cluster, where each machine has its own topic (app.machine-events.*machine-name*). Because order is important on a per-machine basis, and partition-size is not an issue for now, all topics consist of a single partition. Therefore N topics also means N partitions, currently.

The consuming/processing app makes use of kafka-streams, which we've given the `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`/`"application.id"` 'machine-event-processor', which remains the same for each instance, meaning they get put into the same consumer group for Kafka. This consumer is subscribed to the pattern `app.machine-events.*`, as for the processor it does not matter which machine's events it processes. This is verified by `./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group machine-event-processor --members --verbose` showing me a list matching the number of & IPs of all processing services running.

**Expected**

Given 20 machines and 5 instances of the processor, we'd expect each processor to handle ~4 partitions (and therefore ~4 topics).

**Actually**

There's one processor handling 20 partitions (and therefore 20 topics), with 4 other processors doing nothing at all/idling. Killing the 'lucky' processor, all 20 partitions get rebalanced to another processor, resulting in the new processor handling 20 partitions/topics, and 3 processors idling.

**What I've tried so far**

- Check out *[partition.grouper](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#partition-grouper)*. I don't feel like I understand it completely, but as far as I'm able to find, there's only the DefaultPartitioner option anyway, and writing a custom one should not be necessary as (as per the documentation) this setup should work. It does mention that partitions get joined into a task based on their partition key (all 0 for us, as there's only one partition per topic), but I was not able to completely understand this part.
- Used RoundRobinAssignor for the consumer: `settings.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG), new RoundRobinAssignor().getClass.getName)` (Tried several values, as nothing seems to change.)
- Check out other [configuration properties](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java), to see if I've missed something: None, I think.

**The code, simplified**

```
val streamConfig = new Properties
// {producer.metadata.max.age.ms=5000, consumer.metadata.max.age.ms=5000, default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde, consumer.partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor, bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092, application.id=machine-event-processor, default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$ByteArraySerde}
val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
val topicStream: KStream[String, Array[Byte]] = builder.stream(Pattern.compile("app.machine-events.*"))
topicStream.process(new MessageProcessorSupplier(context)) // The event is delegated to a processor, doing the actual processing logic
val eventStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamConfig)
eventStreams.start()
```

**Notes**

- Kafka-streams 2.0.0 is being used:

  `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
     <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0</version>
   </dependency>`
- Kafka is being run inside a container, using the `wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0` version. The docker-stack.yml service:

`kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "$$(netstat -ltn | grep -q 9092)"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "docker info | grep ^Name: | cut -d' ' -f 2"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS: 36000
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s`

- Kafka is setup in a dual-node setup, forming a cluster. Through the docker environment variable we've set the replication factor to `2`, so each partition should have a replication on each node.

**Relevant topics/questions/discussions I've found and checked**

- [KIP-49](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-49+-+Fair+Partition+Assignment+Strategy)
- https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developerguide/partition_assignor.html
- Checked out the Kafka [mail archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/) but did not find anything there
- Checked out [stream example apps](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples)
- All-round searching for others that ran into this issue, but did not give me the answers I need. Also found [KAFKA-7144](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7144) but this should not be an issue for us as we're running 2.0.0

If anyone has run into similar issues, or is able to point out my probably very stupid mistake, please enlighten me!

Comment: I think that you are hitting KAFKA-7144. Note, that "affected version" mark the first version that is affected, and "fixed version" is set to `2.0.1` and `2.1.0`, but not `2.0.0` -- thus, the bug is also in `2.0.0`. `2.1.0` will be released soon. You an try to build Kafka Streams from the sources using `2.0` branch to see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and the typo correction! I completely overlooked the 2.0.1, I reckon. I've gone ahead and tried it with 2.0.1 like you proposed, but it's showing me the same results as before, unfortunately. I've also tried trunk, which is a 2.2.0-snapshot at this point it seems, which ends up in throwing NoSuchMethodException. Might dicuss this some more with a colleague on monday though - I'll let you know if we figure something out.

Comment: Thanks. If the issue is still there in 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT we can look into it -- might be some more issue with balancing the assignment correctly. (Honestly, I did not read the full question in detail yet but wanted to know if you hit KAFKA-7144 or not. If it's something different, we can dig deeper.)

Comment: I've just spent some time in further investigating this - I've built with both the current 2.0 and the 2.1 branch, hooked up the wurstmeister/kafka Dockerfile to the 2.0/2.1 tgz's to build our own 2.X kafka containers, and ran them in a docker swarm. Our own apps are all running 2.0.1/2.1 versions of the dependencies like kafka-streams as well. Results have remained the same, unfortunately. KAFKA-7144 does not seem to be the issue here.

Comment: I've also discussed this issue on the Confluent slack channel, where some have suggested it might be the used assignor and its 'stickiness' causing this. I've tried overwriting this with the RoundRobinAssignor as well, but to no avail. I do remember a point in the Kafka code that kafka-streams uses its own assignor, but I'd have to check that more later.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamsPartitionAssignor.java

Comment: Yesterday I was reading up on the partition.grouper (https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#partition-grouper), default being https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/DefaultPartitionGrouper.html

According to how I understand it, a task is formed with one partition for each subscribed topic. This matches the behavior I'm seeing. However, I was not able to find if a task can be processed by multiple consumers in the same group, or if this is one single task for one single consumer. Would you happen to know?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#example & https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamsPartitionAssignor.java#L381 provide some information about this, and seem to support this theory. I might test it later by adding a dummy topic with multiple partitions, as I get the impression that this might trigger multiple tasks instead of a single task, which should then be balanced over clients/consumers.

Comment: Task are a KafkaStreams concept and created based on input topic partitions and sub-topologies. A task is an atomic unit for parallel processing, and thus, it will be assigned to one consumer in the group. A single consumer can get multiple tasks assigned.

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming that! That confirms the source of our problem, then. I need to find a way to not have all 30+ (single partitioned topic's) partitions get grouped up in one task, as that's what I'm seeing/getting right now, meaning the other consumers get nothing to do.

Comment: That makes sense. Kafka Streams scales via partitions within a topic, but not across topics. That's by design. You could try to use a custom `partition.grouper`, but it's a quite advance interface and you can easily break stuff... -- it might be better though, to use a single topic with one partition per machine and map each machine to a single partition. Note, that you can explicitly specify the target partition on write on the Producer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers running into this same issue, the solution was to not use N topics each having 1 partition, but using 1 topic with N partitions. Even with, say, 120 partitions and 400+ machines/event-sources, multiple event types will be put into the same partition, but this does not affect order of the events.

The implementation was to set the record key to the machine-name, and letting the underlying logic take care of which value goes to which partition. Since we now have a consumer-group with X consumers subscribed to this topic, the partitions are being divided over the consumers evenly, each taking 120/X partitions.

This was as Matthias suggested, which was further confirmed by other helpful people from Confluent at Devoxx Belgium 2018. Thank you!

**Tip**

When using the wurstmeister/kafka docker image, consider using the environment property:

> KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "app.machine-events:120:2"

meaning

> topic-name:number-of-partitions:replication-factor